# Getting error in Python when login to Salesforce

Tags: api, python, simple-salesforce

I am using simple-salesforce 0.74.2 for connecting to Salesforce by using below code,

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce,SalesforceLogin
sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://xxxxx-xxx.my.salesforce.com', username='xxx@xxx.com.xxx', password='xxx@12345')
```

Getting below error:

> You must provide login information or an instance and token'
>   TypeError: You must provide login information or an instance and token

Note: We are using Single sign on so we do not have Token available in Salesforce due to that I can't use token, I want a way where I can login using Authorization may be header but not sure how to pass it.

any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`simple_salesforce` does not provide support for Oauth authentication. It handles authentication via the [SOAP API](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/login.py).

Your options are:

- Authenticate with `simple_salesforce` using username, password, and Organization Id. This works if you have IP whitelisting in use and obviates the need for a security token. (I am not familiar with any SSO implications here, however).

  ```
  sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://xxxxx-xxx.my.salesforce.com', username='xxx@xxx.com.xxx', password='xxx@12345', organizationId='MY_ORG_ID')
  ```
- Authenticate with username, password, and security token. It sounds like you would need to make changes to your organization's configuration to do that.
- Authenticate out-of-band, using some other tool or manually authenticating and extracting your session Id, and provide `simple_salesforce` with a valid Session Id and Instance URL.

  ```
  sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://my.instance.salesforce.com', session_id='XXXXXXX')
  ```

  There's a discussion of this approach (although without a lot more detail) on the `simple_salesforce` [GitHub](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/107). I've implemented JWT Oauth authentication outside of `simple_salesforce` and provided the session Id this way, and it works fine.